# What is the operator precedence of this if statement?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I'm staring at the following expression, written by someone else:

```
if (variableA == CaseA && GetCase(variableB) == CaseA && GetCase(variableC) == CaseA && !CaseB(variableB) || variableA != CaseA)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

What's really tripping me up is this bit:

`!CaseB(variableB) || variableA != CaseA`

Because there aren't any parentheses to group the conditionals together.

How will the C++ compiler evaluate these if statements? If one of the AND operators evaluates to false, does this mean that the OR won't be checked due to short circuit?

**Edit**

Wow, I guess the haters really want to hate today, considering the amount of downvotes for each answer in addition to the -4 (and counting?) for the question. And, uh, no actual explanation for why? Lol.

Stay classy, people. Stay classy. ;)

For the record, simply stating that there's a "left to right evaluation" doesn't really say much in terms of providing a valid answer for the question. I actually did use the great power of Google (which also lead to a few posts here that I read) before posting.

I'll admit my mistake here was failing to mention that, and while I think that the C++ reference is the most natural link to post as a supplement for an answer, the best information I was able to get was inadvertently from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical), via the following quote in a source code example:

`|| has lower precedence than &&`

Which is arguably vague, because "lower precedence" isn't actually specified in terms of what that means in this context.

Either way, to those who actually contributed you will receive an upvote - I'm going to accept the answer which gave me what I was really looking for.

Comment: In terms of precedence, it's just like `a * b * c * d + e`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression is equivalent to:

```
( (variableA == CaseA) && 
  (GetCase(variableB) == CaseA) && 
  (GetCase(variableC) == CaseA) && 
  (!CaseB(variableB))
) 
 || 
(variableA != CaseA)
```

The expression will be evaluated from the top down (because of the short circuit rules), and if any of the first four lines return false, none of the remain first four lines will be evaluated.  If (and only if) one of the first four lines return false, then the final line will be evaluated.

But I am interested that the last line is the negation of the first

Comment: Right idea, but you missed a `)` **and** your explanation inverts the "final line" part.  That "final line" is skipped (rather than evaluated) iff the first four are all true.

Comment: @JSF - thanks!  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Operator `&&` has higher precedence than operator `||` as [seen here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) so all of the `&&` will occur first, then lastly the `||`, in other words if I added parentheses

```
if ((variableA == CaseA && GetCase(variableB) == CaseA && GetCase(variableC) == CaseA && !CaseB(variableB)) || variableA != CaseA)
```

So basically

```
if (all_the_ands || variableA != CaseA)
```

If the left hand side of that expression is `true`, the right hand side will not execute due to short circuiting.

Comment: Please don't spread the "will occur first" myth. It leads people (in one case here on SO, a professor with published C++ books!!) to mistake precedence for evaluation order.

Answer (score 0):

In your example , operator precedence is as below .

! > == > && > ||

So , first statement evaluated would be

1)   !CaseB(variableB)  only if all other "&&" condition happens to be true .If any of "variableA == CaseA && GetCase(variableB) == CaseA && GetCase(variableC) == CaseA " is false then short circuting will happen here and "!CaseB(variableB)" won't be executed .

After that ,

2) if condition 1) is true , again short circuiting( as you have correctly guessed ) else "||" condition will be evaluated .

You are right , if condition 2) happens to be true , other or(||) condition won't even be checked due to short circuit .

Comment: Item (1) of your answer is incorrect because of the short circuiting.

Comment: No it wont.  if variableA != CaseA nothing else will be executed

Comment: @MartinBonner ,JSF : I have made a small program for you guys .int fun()
{
 std::cout<<"\n fun called \n";
 return 1;
}

int main()
{
  
  if( fun() || 1);
}
output : fun called

Comment: Sorry, my comment was incorrect.  If variableA != CaseA the && chain will stop, and the final condition means the whole expression is true - but if the call to CaseB happens, the compiler is utterly broken.

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL You sample program misses the point of your mistake.  Try `int fun() { std::cout<<"\n fun called \n"; return 1; } int main() { if( 0 && !fun()); }`  You said the `!` would happen before the `&&`.  But the `!` never happens at all because the left side of the `&&` happens first.

Comment: @JSF : Agreed , in this condition fun will not be called . yes , i missed it .

Answer (score 0):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

The precedence is as listed in the answer by Sachin Goyal (and as listed more clearly in the above link).

The specific precedence detail that seems to be confusing you is that the `!` associates directly to `CaseB(variableB)` not to anything larger.

The sequence is left to right across each `&&` or `||` with short circuiting.

If the expression to the left of the `!CaseB(variableB) || variableA != CaseA` you asked about is `false` then the `!CaseB(variableB)` is skipped and it evaluates `variableA != CaseA`.  But if the earlier expression is true, it uses the value of `!CaseB(variableB)` to decide whether to evaluate the rest.

The combination of initial test `variableA == CaseA` with final test `variableA != CaseA` seems confused.  It might mean what was intended, but could have been done more simply.

When you code `(X && Y && Z)` the meaning is `((X && Y) && Z)` but because of the way `&&` acts, that is the same as `(X && (Y && Z))`.  So `variableA == CaseA` acts like a guard on the rest of the operands of the `&&`s, so that when that is `false` you skip all the way to the other side of the `||` and make the opposite test and end up resolving `true`.  So it would have been simpler to get the same effect by just starting with `variableA != CaseA ||`